# What HTML parser to choose and why BeautifulSoup doesn't work?

Tags: python, html, python-2.4

I need to parse a HTML-page with *windows-1251* charset (it's in russian).

The problem is that it is the web application and I have to use Python 2.4 without any opportunity to install modules on server. The only thing I tried to do was asking an administrator to install **lxml** module but nevertheless it wasn't built in the right way on 2.4 and attempt to import **lxml.html** fails.

Now I'm trying to select between **BeautifulSoup** and **html5lib** modules, but I didn't find any simple examples of using html5lib (I need just to extract some text from the certain **div** element with stripping all the other tags inside). In turn, BeautifulSoup returns an error ***'junk characters in start tag: u'\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0434\u0430\u0436\u0430>'*** and any attempts to decode the source page from **CP1251** to **unicode** or any other charset didn't make it.

What am i doing wrong? Or what parser I should use?

Comment: What release of BeautifulSoup are you using?  See http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/3.1-problems.html , avoid `3.1.*` (unless you're using Python 3) and stick with `3.0.x` (for `x >= 8`).

Comment: I'm using 3.0.8.1 because of Python 2.4. It's the main problem that Python version is so old.

Comment: Your error message looks like you already have Unicode objects.  Are you sure you are really reading binary string data encoded in CP1251 and that it's not getting converted to unicode somewhere in the stack?

Comment: AFAIK BeautifulSoup can use `chardet` which can autodetect cp1251 quite happily even if the encoding is not supplied in the HTML. In any case as Peter Lyons as pointed out, `\u04xx` looks like Cyrillic already in unicode to me.

Answer (score 0):

This question has a great answer on how to convert to UTF-8:

[Python: how to convert from Windows 1251 to Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806980/python-how-to-convert-from-windows-1251-to-unicode)

I love the BeautifulSoup library but I'm not familiar with odd character sets. If I were writing this I'd probably just try to sanitize the input to get me into unicode land where most libraries are able to play nicely.