# Parsing multiple vCards with Python

Tags: python, vcf-vcard, vobject

I've got a vcf file from Google's contacts export feature.
It was encoded with UTF-8, but my WinMobile telephone expects win1251 characters to import into contactbook.
I recoded it into win1251 and did try to parse the file using [vObject](http://vobject.skyhouseconsulting.com/) library.
What I got as a result was a mix of fields some of which were correctly encoded into Unicode, and some were replaced by "?????" text.
For example I include a prettyPrint of such a contact:

```
 VCARD
    TEL: +7812000000
    params for  TEL:
       aKey TYPE [u'CELL']
    TEL: +7921000000
    params for  TEL:
       aKey TYPE [u'HOME']
    URL: http\://www.diamantstroy.spb.ru
    X-ABLABEL: _$!<HomePage>!$_
    N:  Alexei  ??????? 
    VERSION: 3.0
    ORG: [u'\u041e\u041e\u041e \u0414\u0438\u0430\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0442-\u0421\u0442\u0440\u043e\u0439-\u0421\u0435\u0440\u0432\u0438\u0441']
    FN: Alexei ???????
```

What I cannot find is a place in the source-code where I should apply some sort of encode()/decode() patch to fit my needs.
Could someone help me?

Comment: It is a little confusing what flow you are going thru. Are you doing phone -> google -> code, or since you use the word expects, are you doing google -> code -> phone?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your input is unicode when you pass it to `readOne` (or whatever parsing function you are using).  If you want to go back to Windows-1251 coding, after you parse the vcard use `result.encode('cp1251')` or `codecs.open(filename, 'w', 'cp1251').write(result)`.

It is a little confusing what flow you are going thru. Are you doing `phone -> google -> code`,
or since you use the word [expects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15269797/2087463),
are you doing `google -> code -> phone`?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5807248/2087463) may help with conversions.