# Encoding Issues with BeautifulSoup Parsing and Scraping

Tags: html, python-3.x, encoding, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Utilizing Python3, BeautifulSoup and very minimal regex, I'm trying to scrape the text off of this webpage:

http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/?pid=2921

I have already succesfully extracted its html into a file. In fact I've done this with almost all of the presidential speeches available on this website; I have 247 (out of 258 possible) speeches' html saved locally on my computer.

My code for extracting just the text off of each page looks like this:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('scan_here.txt') as reference:       #'scan_here.txt' is a file containing all the pages whose html I have downloaded successfully
    for line in reference:
        line_unclean = reference.readline() #each file's name is just a random string of 5-6 integers
        line = str(re.sub(r'\n', '', line_unclean)) #for removing '\n' from each file name
        f = open(('local_path_to_folder_containing_all_the_html_files\\') + line)
        doc = f.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')
        for speech in soup.select('span.display-text'):
            final_speech = str(speech)
            print(final_speech)
```

Utilizing this code, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extract_individual_speeches.py", line 11, in <module>
    doc = f.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 56443: invalid start byte
```

I understand this is a decode error and have tried to run this code on other html files, not just the first one which appears on the list of file names in 'scan_text.txt'. Same error, so I think it's an encoding issue local to the html files.

I think the problem might lie with this third line of the html, which has the same encoding for all my html files:

```
<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

What is 'windows-1251?' I assume it's the problem here. I've looked it up and seen there are some windows-1251 to UTF-8 converters, but I didn't see one which works well with Python.

I found this [SO thread which seems to deal with this issue of conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806980/python-how-to-convert-from-windows-1251-to-unicode), but I'm not sure how to integrate it with my existing code.

Any help on this issue is much appreciated, TIA.

Answer (score 2):

'windows-1251' is a standard Windows encoding. What you need is UTF-8. You can define an encoding when you open a file.

Try something like this:

```
with open(file,'r',encoding='windows-1251') as f:
  text = f.read()
```

or:

```
text = text.decode('windows-1251')
```

You can also use codecs:

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open(file,'r','windows-1251').read()
codecs.open(file,'w','UTF-8').write(f)
```

Comment: Hi Peter S., thanks for the answers. I don't even know if it's an issue with the html file's encoding, though, because when I manually save it as UTF-8 I get the same error message.

Comment: Remove BOM from the file and try text = text.encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='replace')

Comment: Oh I see, it's a different format which details the byte sequence. I didn't save it with UTF-8 BOM, just regular UTF-8.